# Connect by prior with changing rules

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical, connect-by

I have a table like this:

```
dataid | parentid  |   name
----------------------------
   1   |     99    |  root 
----------------------------
   2   |     -1     | folder1 
----------------------------
   3   |     -1     | folder2 
----------------------------
   4   |    -1    |  file1 
----------------------------
   5   |     2     |  file2
```

So rules are pretty weird. All of the items in a table are children of root. When folder is inside root it's parentid is negative, when file is inside root it's parentid is negative. But when file or folder is inside folder indise root it's parentid is positive.

So far I've written this query and it works with allways positive parents

```
SELECT name , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF "IsLeaf",
   LEVEL, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(dataid, '/') "Path"
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE 1=1
   START WITH dataid = 99
   CONNECT BY PRIOR dataid = abs(parentid);
```

So, I've managed to make it work using abs. BUT it takes too much time. Is therer another solution or maybe I should create an index...

Comment: Looks like you need `ABS(parentid)`

Comment: What happens if you have more than 99 files or folders? Better set `parentid` of "root" to NULL which is more logical to "has no parent".

Comment: Guys, sorry, changed rules a bit. When something is inside root it's parent is negative, but since level two it's positive. So solution with abs does not work

Comment: I just tested exactly with your data and with `connect by abs(parentid) = prior dataid`, it works.

Comment: Ok, it works, I found my mistake - I have to exchange dataid and abs(parentid) in CONNECT TO PRIOR clause.

Still - takes too much time.

Comment: Create a functional index on abs(parentid) like so:
CREATE INDEX thisidx ON table (abs(parentid));

Comment: How many rows do you have and how do you define "too much time"?